# Has Apple approved any SDL based iphone apps on the Appstore?

Tags: iphone, app-store, sdl

I'm looking to port an existing game of my own to from SDL 1.2 on linux SDL 1.3 on the iphone. While I'm fairly happy that SDL 1.3 provides the features I want I do not know if this will damage my chances off this getting accepted by apple.

Has anyone had an SDL app accepted? If anyone has had one rejected, were the reasons due to SDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [Angry Birds](http://www.libsdl.org/games.php?match_id=2088) is an SDL based game!. See also the [Galaxy Gameworks](http://www.galaxygameworks.com/testimonials.html)  site that used to offer libSDL under a commercial license.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine. Apple does not receive your source, only an uploaded binary. There shouldn't really be any licensing issues as far as I can tell. I think the only limitation would be whether or not SDL 1.3 compiles and runs well on the iPhone.

Comment: Thank-you, I had not realised that I would send apple builds. That makes things a whole lot easier.

Comment: "Apple does not receive your source, only an uploaded binary." Yet Apple's rejecting people for accessing private APIs, and for a while they were rejecting Phonegap apps.

Comment: They are either scanning the binaries for symbols corresponding to private API calls or detecting the use of private APIs as the application runs.  No one submits source code to Apple for approval.

Comment: "Yet Apple's rejecting people for accessing private APIs, and for a while they were rejecting Phonegap apps." This is true, but this is only for using functions in the volatile, private API that works with Apple's hardware (such as video capture through the phone.) In fact, just recently they began allowing use of UIGetScreenImage(), a private API call to get a screen cap. This came with the stipulation, "When we update the OS, you update your app." The private API rejections are just so they can change the unfinished API without promising your app will work. Not middleware, their private API.